# Javascript syntax specification for methods parameters on Mozilla developer network

Tags: javascript, syntax

The [MDN Web Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) describes the syntax for use in JavaScript standard built in objects methods, using brackets to group the available parameters.

For example:

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
// Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

This has been causing some confusion for me while reading the documentation and I can not understand the purpose of grouping the parameters with brackets.

For instance, in the example above, why are the index and array parameters grouped as so.

```
callback(currentValue[, index[, array]])
```

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: The brackets symbolize optional parameters.

Comment: because you can't pass a second argument if you don't pass a first one

Comment: Thankyou, I understand perfectly now, I would hope to (currently do not have the privileges) up vote these comments as for a beginner they are very helpful, regarding grouping by precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an attempt to indicate that they're optional. You could do

```
.map(function callback(currentValue) { ... })
```

or

```
.map(function callback(currentValue, index) { ... })
```

or

```
.map(function callback(currentValue, index, array) { ... })
```

It's up to you and what you need in the callback.

This specific case isn't a great use of that, because your `callback` will **always** receive three arguments, regardless of how many formal parameters you declare that it accepts. But that notation, putting optional parameters in square brackets, is fairly common when indicating what a function requires vs. what's optional.

Comment: As a relative beginner, I have been learning with video tutorials, and as such I was unaware of such a notation. This makes complete sense now. Thank you very much for the clarification!

Comment: @Sam - That's the problem with notation conventions. If you don't know them, you...don't know them. They aren't very discoverable. :-)